# Limit number of devices per user in Crashlytics Beta

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

Can I limit number of devices ( or installations) for a beta user?
I want to set a maximum of 2 devices per user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Currently, it isn't possible to limit the number of devices per tester.

Comment: Does Google have any library to limit devices per user?

Comment: None that I know of.